# Evaluating a highlighted expression in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I can add a watch expression, I can type `p foo.bar()` in gdb console panel, but what I want is to highlight a function call while debugging is paused and have a popup panel show me the result. Is this possible?